# Node.js socket.io handling users

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So at my server app when I get a socket request I send data based on what user is requesting the information...

```
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('login', function(data) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1', [data.name, data.password], function(err, result) {
            if(result.length === 0)
            {
                socket.emit('login-failed');
            }
            else
            {
                if(users.check(result[0].name))
                {
                    result[0].socket = socket.id;
                    users.add(result[0]);
                    console.log(colors.yellow('User: ' + result[0].name + ' connected.'));
                    socket.emit('login-success');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

So when a user logs in I save some information like username, password, socketid.

```
var userList = [];

exports.add = function(data)
{
    userList.push(data);
}

exports.check = function(data)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++)
    {
        if(userList[i].name === data)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

exports.remove = function(id)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++)
    {
        if(userList[i].socket === id)
        {
            var index = userList.indexOf(i);
            userList.splice(index, 1);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

So as you can see Im saving users data that I will access later for example on here

```
socket.on('test', function(data) {
   if(users.remove(socket.id)) console.log('Yes');
});
```

But the only way I have to identify a socket is by using its socket.id, now my question is if I can really trust socketid or if I should use another 'system' to actually manage my users logic.

I cant really figure any other system to actually check what socket is calling my server

Comment: I am using socket.id in my system.Socket.id is unique so you can trust.

Comment: You can trust them, they're like session ids